# Try is executing but catch is not caching the error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to test for https connection.
The "try" is executing but "catch" is not caching the error and executing the code as desired.

I'm using node.js

```
var https = require("https");

  try {

  https.get({host:'nonsecuredomain.com'}, function(res){});

  }

  catch(err) {

  console.log('maybe an ssl error');

  }
```

events.js:167
         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
         ^

```
Error: certificate has expired
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1049:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:631:8)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Probably because it's asynchronous.

Comment: The call to https.get doesn't fail - so the catch block doesn't pick it up. You need to look at the response coming back into your empty callback function `function(res){})`,

Answer (score 3):

`https.get` is asynchronous. This means the function with the `try` `catch` will have already returned by the time the network returns a result or error.

`get` returns an object that will emit events on errors. You should listen for that 'error' event and handle the errors that were thrown asynchronously there:

```
https.get(url, (res) => {
    res.on('data', (d) => {
       // do stuff
    });
}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e); // deal with errors
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As taplar mentioned, the error happens on an other thread, you cant catch it on the original thread.

Usually the async function returns a promise and you can handle it by 
asyncFunc().catch(err => console.error(err. message))

But in this case the async function returns an event so you need to handle it this way

```
https.get({host:'foo.bar'}, function onSuccess(res){
    res.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`)
    })
}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`)
});
```